# POSIX alternative to GNU find's -printf predicate

Tags: find, posix, portability, printf

I'd like to rewrite these 2 commands so they will use only [POSIX-compliant switches](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html):

```
find "$TARGET_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '(DIR)  %f\n'
find "$TARGET_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s  %f  ' -exec file -b {} \;
```

`-maxdepth 1` can probably be replaced with `-prune`, but `-printf` will require a more complicated redirection.

Comment: `printf '(DIR) %s\n' "$TARGET_DIR/"*/` should work for the first, I think, but just to be sure - what does `%f` do *(I forget?)*.

Comment: FYI, `-prune` equates to `-maxdepth 0` not `-maxdepth 1`.  Related: [Limit POSIX find to specific depth?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/135943)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find "$TARGET_DIR//." \( -name . -o -prune \) -type d -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    f=${f%//.}
    f=${f%"${f##*[!/]}"}
    f=${f##*/}
    printf "(DIR) %s\n" "${f:-/}"
  done' sh {} +
```

It would be simpler for the equivalent of `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`:

```
find "$TARGET_DIR//." \( -name . -o -prune \) -type d -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    printf "(DIR) %s\n" "${f##*/}"
  done' sh {} +
```

For the second one:

```
find "$TARGET_DIR//." ! -name . -prune -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    size=$(($(wc -c < "$f") +0)) || continue
    printf %s "$size ${f##*/} "
    file -b -- "$f"
  done' sh {} +
```

Comment: wouldn't be better to read the size with `stat`?