# Limit POSIX find to specific depth?

Tags: find, posix

I noticed recently that [POSIX specifications for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) do not include the `-maxdepth` primary.

For those unfamiliar with it, the purpose of the `-maxdepth` primary is to restrict how many levels deep `find` will descend.  `-maxdepth 0` results in *only* command line arguments being processed; `-maxdepth 1` would only handle results directly within the command line arguments, etc.

How can I get the equivalent behavior to the non-POSIX `-maxdepth` primary using only POSIX-specified options and tools?

(Note: Of course I can get the equivalent of `-maxdepth 0` by just using `-prune` as the first operand, but that doesn't extend to other depths.)

Comment: @StevenPenny, FreeBSD's `-depth -2`, `-depth 1`... approach could be seen as better than GNU's `-maxdepth`/`-mindepth`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas either way - POSIX find should have one or the other; else it is crippled

Comment: At least for `-maxdepth`/`-mindepth`, there are reasonable alternatives (note that `-path` is a recent addition to POSIX). The alternatives for `-timexy` or `-mtime -3m` (or `-mmin -3`) are a lot more cumbersome. Some like `-execdir`/`-delete` have no reliable alternative.

Comment: @StevenPenny, feel free to log a ticket at http://austingroupbugs.net/ to request it be added. I've seen things get added without the need for a sponsor when there was a strong justification. A probably better course of action would be to get as many implementations add it first so POSIX would just have to specify the existing which is generally less contentious.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas in my case I ended up just naming the files directly, but thank you; I might file a ticket if this comes up again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `-path` to match a given depth and prune there. Eg

```
find . -path '*/*/*' -prune -o -type d -print
```

would be maxdepth 1, as `*` matches the `.`, `*/*` matches `./dir1`, and `*/*/*` matches `./dir1/dir2` which is pruned. If you use an absolute starting directory you need to add a leading `/` to the `-path` too.

Comment: Hmmm, tricky.  Couldn't you just remove one layer of `/*` from the end of the pattern, take out the `-o`operator, and get the same result?

Comment: No, because `*` matches `/` as well, so the dir `a/b/c/d/e` would fit `-path */*`, sadly.

Comment: But `a/b/c/d/e` would never be *reached*, because `-prune` would be applied to `a/b`....

Comment: Sorry, I misread that `-prune` and `-o` were removed. If you keep the `-prune` the problem is that the `*/*` will not match anything at a level above the maxdepth, eg the single directory `a`.

Answer (score 25):

@meuh's approach is inefficient as his `-maxdepth 1` approach still lets `find` read the content of directories at level 1 to later ignore them otherwise. It will also not work properly with some `find` implementations (including GNU `find`) if some directory names contain sequences of bytes  that don't form valid characters in the user's locale (like for file names in a different character encoding).

```
find . \( -name . -o -prune \) -extra-conditions-and-actions
```

is the more canonical way to implement GNU's `-maxdepth 1`.

Generally though, it's depth 1 you want (`-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`) as you don't want to consider `.` (depth 0), and then it's even simpler:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -extra-conditions-and-actions
```

For `-maxdepth 2`, that becomes:

```
find . \( ! -path './*/*' -o -prune \) -extra-conditions-and-actions
```

And that's where you run in the invalid character issues.

For instance, if you have a directory called `Stéphane` but that `é` is encoded in the iso8859-1 (aka latin1) charset (0xe9 byte) as was most common in Western Europe and the America up until the mid 2000s, then that 0xe9 byte is not a valid character in UTF-8. So, in UTF-8 locales, the `*` wildcard (with some `find` implementations) will not match `Stéphane` as `*` is 0 or more *characters* and 0xe9 is not a character.

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ find . -maxdepth 2
.
./St?phane
./St?phane/Chazelas
./Stéphane
./Stéphane/Chazelas
./John
./John/Smith
$ find . \( ! -path './*/*' -o -prune \)
.
./St?phane
./St?phane/Chazelas
./St?phane/Chazelas/age
./St?phane/Chazelas/gender
./St?phane/Chazelas/address
./Stéphane
./Stéphane/Chazelas
./John
./John/Smith
```

My `find` (when the output goes to a terminal) displays that invalid 0xe9 byte as `?` above. You can see that `St<0xe9>phane/Chazelas` was not `prune`d.

You can work around it by doing:

```
LC_ALL=C find . \( ! -path './*/*' -o -prune \) -extra-conditions-and-actions
```

But note that that affects all the locale settings of `find` and any application it runs (like via the `-exec` predicates).

```
$ LC_ALL=C find . \( ! -path './*/*' -o -prune \)
.
./St?phane
./St?phane/Chazelas
./St??phane
./St??phane/Chazelas
./John
./John/Smith
```

Now, I really get a `-maxdepth 2` but note how the é in the second Stéphane properly encoded in UTF-8 is displayed as `??` as the 0xc3 0xa9 bytes (considered as two individual undefined characters in the C locale) of the UTF-8 encoding of é are not printable characters in the C locale.

And if I had added a `-name '????????'`, I would have gotten the wrong Stéphane (the one encoded in iso8859-1).

To apply to arbitrary paths instead of `.`, you'd do:

```
find some/dir/. ! -name . -prune ...
```

for `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` or:

```
find some/dir/. \( ! -path '*/./*/*' -o -prune \) ...
```

for `-maxdepth 2`.

I would still do a:

```
(cd -P -- "$dir" && find . ...)
```

First because that makes the paths shorter which makes it less likely to run into *path too long* or *arg list too long* issues but also to work around the fact that `find` can't support arbitrary path arguments (except with `-f` with FreeBSD `find`) as it will choke on values of `$dir` like `!` or `-print`...

---

The `-o` in combination with negation is a common trick to run two independent sets of `-condition`/`-action` in `find`.

If you want to run `-action1` on files meeting `-condition1` and independently `-action2` on files meeting `-condition2`, you cannot do:

```
find . -condition1 -action1 -condition2 -action2
```

As `-action2` would only be run for files that meet *both* conditions.

Nor:

```
find . -contition1 -action1 -o -condition2 -action2
```

As `-action2` would not be run for files that meet *both* conditions.

```
find . \( ! -condition1 -o -action1 \) -condition2 -action2
```

works as `\( ! -condition1 -o -action1 \)` would resolve to *true* for every file. That assumes `-action1` is an action (like `-prune`, `-exec ... {} +`) that always returns *true*. For actions like `-exec ... \;` that may return *false*, you may want to add another `-o -something` where `-something` is harmless but returns *true* like `-true` in GNU `find` or `-links +0` or `! -name ''` or `-name '*'` (though note the issue about invalid characters above).

Comment: Someday I will run into a bunch of Chinese files and I'll be very glad I've read your many answers about locale and valid characters.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard, you (and even more so a Chinese person) is more likely to run into problem with British, French... file names than Chinese file names as Chinese filenames are more often encoded in UTF-8 than file names of alphabetical scripts that can generally be covered by a single-byte charset which was the norm up until relatively recently. There are other multi-byte charsets to cover Chinese character, but I'd expect Chinese people would have switched to UTF-8 earlier than westerners as those charsets have a number of nasty issues. See also the edit for an example.

Comment: How does your boolean expression equivalent for `-maxdepth 2` work? Assume, I have `PATH_1=/a/b/c/d` and `PATH_2=/a/b/c/d/e`, and I'm going `-maxdepth 2` from `/a/b`, and `d` and `e` are files, not dirs.  

`!` negates, so it would negate the outcome of the `-path` primary. With `-path '/a/b/*/*'`, `PATH_1` matches and is `true` then negated to `false`. The `-o` causes us to go `-prune`, but `d` is a file so nothing happens. The path is then printed to `stdout`. 

`PATH_2` doesn't match `-path '/a/b/*/*' and is `false`, then negated to `true`. What happens now?

Comment: Apologies, the comment above looks like a wall of text. I tried adding line breaks with SHIFT+ENTER and it didn't work out :( I appreciate your help in understanding this.

Comment: @Ungeheuer, not sure what you mean if `d` is not a directory, then `find` will never come across a `d/e` file.

Comment: My bad! Wasn't paying attention `PATH_1=/a/b/c/d`, `PATH_2=/a/b/c/e/f`. `e` is a directory at the same level as `d`, and `f` is the regular file.

Comment: @Ungeheuer, `-prune` returns true (like GNU find's `-true`) with the added side effect that if applied on a file of type *directory*, `find` will not descend into it. So if you do `find /a/b/.`, `/a/b/./c/e` will match `-path '*/./*/*'` and so `-prune` will be applied to it and `find` will not look for files into it,  so will never come across `/a/b/./c/e/f`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where I needed a way to limit depth when searching multiple paths (instead of just `.`).

For example:

```
$ find dir1 dir2 -name myfile -maxdepth 1
```

This led me to an alternate approach using -regex. The gist is:

```
-regex '(<list of paths | delimited>)/<filename>'
```

So, the above would be:

```
$ find dir1 dir2 -name myfile -regextype awk -regex '(dir1|dir2)/myfile' # GNU
$ find -E dir1 dir2 -name myfile -regex '(dir1|dir2)/myfile' # MacOS BSD
```

Without a filename:

```
$ find dir1 dir2 -name myfile -maxdepth 1 # GNU

-regex '(<list of paths | delimited>)/<anything that's not a slash>$'

$ find dir1 dir2 -name myfile -regextype awk -regex '(dir1|dir2)/[^/]*$' # GNU
$ find -E dir1 dir2 -name myfile -regex '(dir1|dir2)/[^/]*$' # MacOS BSD
```

Finally, for `-maxdepth 2` the regex changes to: `'(dir1|dir2)/([^/]*/){0,1}[^/]*$'`

Comment: This question asks for a standard (as in POSIX) solution though.  Also `-maxdepth` would work with multiple search paths.