# How to list files with a particular pattern created in the last 30 days in unix

Tags: ksh

I'm using the below command but it is not working

```
find . PYRLLPS_GL_201610D2* -maxdepth 1 -mtime -30
```

I get the below error

```
find: bad option -maxdepth
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

Comment: Btw. you may want to use `find . -name 'PYRLLPS_GL_201610D2*' …` instead. Without `-name` the shell has to read the current directory, expand the glob expression, pass all results to `find`, which in turn will filter for modification time. With `-name`, `find` will take care of everything, and no potentially large argument list needs to be passed around.

Answer (score 0):

`-maxdepth` is not [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).  It appears your version of `find` doesn't support that primary.

Ways to accomplish the same effect using only POSIX options are discussed here:

- [Limit POSIX find to specific depth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/135943)

---

Also, it's unclear what you're trying to do but you **may** have the usage of `find` itself confused:

If you are trying to find all files with names that start with `PYRLLPS_GL_201610D2`, you should be using the `-name` operator, and protecting the pattern itself from expansion (shell globbing) so that `find` *sees* the pattern itself, rather than the pattern being expanded by the shell.

Something like so:

```
find . -path '*/*/*' -prune -o -name PYRLLPS_GL_201610D2\* -mtime -30 -print
```

If you are trying to find all files with `-mtime -30` that are directly within either the current directory or within one of the `PYRLLPS_GL_201610D2*` directories in the current directory, then you have the right idea and are just missing the `-maxdepth` workaround linked above.

Comment: I used find . -name PYRLLPS_GL_201610D2\* -mtime -60 -print but it lists only one file whereas i have more than one file. I want all the files created or modified in the last 30 days. when i used -30 no output was provided, but i have files in the last 30 days

Comment: @DhivyaBalaPalanisamy, put ``some `backticks` `` around your inline code, please.  I take it you included the backslash before the `*`?  That part is important.

Comment: Anyway, if you are getting a new error, please [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/277464/edit) to include the new information.  My answer as currently written *does* explain the error in your original post, and the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name PYRLLPS_GL_201610D2*  -mtime -30
```

If you want to find file named like PYRLLPS_GL_201610D2AAAA ,you need the code:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'PYRLLPS_GL_201610D2*'  -mtime -30
```