# for loop to evaluate multiple directories and execute command

Tags: shell, solaris, ksh, for

I was editing a shell script and I want to know how can use for to use all directories listed by a list or variables and then execute a command.

**Example:**

I have this directories:

```
/dirname1/app1
/dirname1/app2
/dirname2/app1
/dirname2/app2
```

The thing is each directory have 8 application directory, and I need to get the value of each one using du for usage of each one.

I have this example piece of code that I made, but I want to convert it more better than the actually have.

```
#!/bin/ksh

#files="/dev /etc"
inc=1

for f in /*;
do
vari=`du -ksh $f`
        [ -d $f ]

echo "The value of each one is: ------ : $((inc++)): $vari"
done;

echo "Execution Done."
exit 0
```

I hope to be cleared with this,

Comment: This really isn't clear.  Are you attempting to check if `$f` is a directory?  If so your syntax is wrong; you don't have an `if` statement anywhere.  Do you have `app1` through `app8` in each of `dirname1` and `dirname2`, and you want to list the summarized usage for each `appN` directory?

Comment: **and you want to list the summarized usage for each appN directory?**

Yes, I want the usage summary of each app from app1 to app8 in each directory. I put this piece of code just for example, Im trying to make the easy way to make it but, Im newbie learning shell scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is keep things simple.  **Don't write a whole script when there is a ready-made tool that already does what you want.**

`du` is the tool for reporting on disk usage, and `find` is the tool for finding files.  Use them together.

```
find dirname* -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -hs {} \;
```

---

`-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` are GNU extensions; to handle this portably you need a slightly trickier command as described here:

- [Limit POSIX find to specific depth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/135943)

The command in this case would be either

```
find dirname* -path '*/*' -prune -type d -exec du -hs {} \;
```

or, if all of your `dirname*` directories are within, say, `topdirectory` and there are no other directories in there, use:

```
find topdirectory -path '*/*/*' -prune -type d -exec du -hs {} \;
```

This will only report on the directories within the directories within `topdirectory`, which seems to be what you're asking for.

---

**Update:** I took another look at this and actually, you can do what you need entirely with shell globbing:

```
du -hs dirname*/app*/
```

Your directory are probably not actually named like this, but you could even run `du -hs */*` and it would work—it just might include some other directories (or files) you didn't want to list, depending on how clean (uncluttered) you keep those directories.

Comment: Im using Solaris 10/11. An I got an error.

**find: bad option -maxdepth**
**find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list**

Any idea how can I use this in this oss?

Comment: @vicdeveloper, sorry, my first command is no good for Solaris.  I've updated my answer; try one of the other methods I suggested.

Comment: I got this error: 

**find: bad option -path**

Any idea?

Comment: @vicdeveloper Wow, I haven't used Solaris and now I'm glad of that.  :)  Updated with the really simple answer.  Hope that works for you?

Comment: Yes, I tried that one, but, the thing is that the execution time is very large, and it takes around 15 minutes for each app directory, many of then sizes around 1,2 gb and greater than it.

It is possible try to optimize the result of time?

Comment: @vicdeveloper, that's a completely separate issue.  The command does what you want; any command that actually checks the disk usage *right now* of several GB of files is going to take a bit of time.  That's the nature of the task.

Comment: I wonder if you've really expressed what you're *actually* trying to solve.  Perhaps checking total disk usage (using `df`) would be sufficient.  How often is the usage expected to change?  I don't have enough information to make an intelligent decision about what you should do—only you have that info.  I did answer your specific question, though.  ;)

Comment: Great. It Works. :D!. I passed many directories as parameters in the same command and it shows me the info that I want.

Thanks.

Comment: that Update should be `du -sh dirname*/app*/` (with a trailing `/`) if you want to run `du` only on *sub-directories* matching `app*` but not *files* matching `app*`.

Comment: @cas, excellent point; updated.