# Remove files containing certain characters

Tags: files, grep, rm

I have a list of files in a directory and I need to remove every file that contains either a 0 or a 7. I feel like I need to use grep but I'm not too sure. Any ideas?

Comment: every file that contains either a 0 or a 7 ---> we have to check in filename or contents of file ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is evaluate your files according to a specific conditional test, and perform an action on each file according to the result of the conditional test.  This is the exact purpose of the `find` command.

Here is a portable ([POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)) command to remove regular files that have a contents including a "0" or a "7":

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q '[07]' {} \; -exec rm {} +
```

Note that **this *recursively* searches the current directory.**

If that's not what you want, you can check if the `-maxdepth` primary is available (in which case you may as well use the primary `-delete` as well; neither is specified by POSIX):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -q '[07]' {} \; -delete
```

Or, you could apply the techniques given in:

- [Limit POSIX find to specific depth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/135943)

Comment: If there's no requirement for recursion here this could be done a lot simpler with `ls *[0,7]*` (to verify what files match) and then `rm -v *[0,7]*`. Your answer is a lot fancier though.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -l '[07]' DirToYourFiles/* | xargs rm -f
```

`grep -l` means list filenames only

`[07]` means either 0 or 7

`xargs` makes them a command.

That assumes file names don't contain blanks, newline, single quote, double quote or backslash characters. With GNU utilities, you can make it more reliable with:

```
grep -lZ '[07]' DirToYourFiles/* | xargs -r0 rm -f
```

Comment: This will not handle whitespace in filenames gracefully.  And adding `-f` is *not* called for.

Comment: Also see: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)