# Shell script with directory input

Tags: shell-script, csh

I'm writing a shell script that is supposed to take in one parameter (a directory name) and display how many files, directories, readable files, writable files and executable files are in that directory. If a parameter isn't given when you run it, its supposed to display an error message and abort. If the given parameter doesn't exist it should also display an error message and abort. Otherwise it should display the above info. I cannot for the life of me get it to run. Here is what I have, please help!:

```
   #!/bin/csh
   $1
   set file=$1
       if ($file==0)then
             echo "usage: assignment6.sh <directory_name>"
             exit0
       else
           if (-e $file && -r $file) then
                echo "Number of Directories: `ls | wc -w`"
                echo "Number of Files: `ls -d */ | wc -w`"
                echo "Number of Readable files: `find * -type f -or -type d -maxdepth 0 -perm +u=r | wc -w`"
                echo "Number of Writable files: `find * -type f -or -type d -maxdepth 0 -perm +u=w | wc -w`"
                echo "Number of Executable files: `find * -type f -or -type d -maxdepth 0 -perm +u=x | wc -w`"

            else
                if (! -e $file) echo "No such directory."
                exit 0
            endif
       endif
 exit 0
```

Comment: In what language is that script written?

Comment: yeah it's bash.

Comment: Sorry, mind block. It's `csh`. In my defense I was never a fan of `csh` and I haven't used it in the last 20 years...

Comment: No it's not `bash`, it's `csh`. In `bash` the `if` construct is `if` condition `; then` then-part `else` else-part `fi`. In `csh` it is like you wrote, `if (`condition`) then` then-part `else` else-part `endif`. In `bash` assignment is plain variable`=`value -- `set` is from `csh`.

Comment: @Maddie, if this is `csh` you should add the proper shebang to the top of your script `#!/bin/csh`

Comment: i have the shebang and i guess its csh (i'm new to unix), i've modeled the if/else statements just like my professor's in his powerpoints

Comment: You seem to be missing an `endif`.

Comment: i just fixed that, but i'm still getting the if: expression syntax error :(

Comment: Your last if statement is not following the `if () then` syntax.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input, but I unfortunately am still getting the same error

Comment: @Maddie: Are you required to use csh?   If you are, say so.   If you aren’t, [don’t](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot "Csh Programming Considered Harmful").

Answer (score 2):

Issues in this script:

1. You are parsing the output of `ls`.  [Don't parse `ls`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943)
2. You are relying on filenames not to contain spaces *or newlines.*  [They can contain either.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)
3. You're using `csh`.  All by itself, [that's a bad idea for shell scripts.](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)  Bash, Ksh, Zsh, almost *anything* but `csh` is a better idea.  (My opinion, but read through the linked factual reasoning.)

Here is a POSIX compliant version of part of this program.  (If I have time later I may include the rest of the features.)

This won't handle cases where there are more files than fit in an argument list, but it could be modified to do so if *really* necessary.

```
#!/bin/sh

[ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ -d "$1" ] || {
  printf 'Usage:\t%s <directory>\n' "$0"
  exit 1
}

dirs="$(find "$1" -path '*/*/*' -prune -o -type d -exec sh -c 'printf %s\\n "$#"' sh {} +)"
files="$(find "$1" -path '*/*/*' -prune -o -type f -exec sh -c 'printf %s\\n "$#"' sh {} +)"

printf 'Number of directories in %s:\t%s\n' "$1" "$dirs"
printf 'Number of files in %s:\t%s\n' "$1" "$files"
```

---

Since the `-maxdepth` primary is not portable, I made use of the techniques described here:

- [Limit POSIX find to specific depth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/135943)

Comment: Actually this will report one directory too many, as it reports itself.  Unfortunately I don't have time to work on it further at this moment.

Comment: Also, unless I'm misunderstanding, it will fail if there are so many files / directories, or their names are so long, that they cannot be passed on a single command line. But +1 for everything else.

Comment: @G-Man, correct; I mentioned that actually.  Feel free to make an edit if you think that wasn't made clear enough.

Comment: @G-Man, I haven't made the necessary huge number of files to test, but I *believe* all that would be necessary to handle vast numbers of files would be `dirs="$(printf %s "$dirs" | tr '\n' + | bc)"`.  Right?

Comment: Sorry; it's clear enough.  I read it too quickly and skidded over that paragraph. … … … I can't get your answer to work; I believe that you need `(printf "%s" "$dirs" | tr '\n' +; echo) | bc`.  Or (much as I hate to use unquoted variables), `echo $dirs | tr " " + | bc`.