# print all 3-character-sub-directories using shell script in AIX

Tags: shell-script, directory, aix

In my system, there is a `/Test` directory under which many directories are available. I want to print all directories with 3-character-name, in AIX system.

I got code for Gnu/Linux.

```
find /test -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk -F / 'length($NF) == 3' |awk -F / '{print $3} '
```

This is an AIX server.

ex : /test
directory contains sub directories

```
test1
AAA
BBB
Test2
test3
```

required output :

```
AAA
BBB
```

Comment: could you please [edit] your question to make it a bit more clear ? Also did you installed the gnu tools on AIX ? or Are you  using the basic tools of AIX ?

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: i'm looking for unix command

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

See [Limit POSIX find to specific depth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637) for the standard equivalent of GNU `find`'s `-maxdepth` predicate. So here:

```
(cd /Test && find . ! -name . -prune -type d -name '???') | sed 's|\./||'
```

Or if `zsh` is installed:

```
zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" /Test/???(D/:t)'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple shell loop solution would be to do

```
for pathname in Test/???/; do
    printf '%s\n' "$( basename "$pathname" )"
done
```

This would print each subdirectory name that matches the given pattern (or names of symbolic links to subdirectories).

If you want to do anything other than *listing* the names, then you would do something like

```
for pathname in Test/???/; do
    # some code using "$pathname" here
done
```

I.e., you would *not* first generate the list and then iterate over it.

Comment: find Test -type d -name '???'  -- this command finding 3 character sub directory for each sub directory. i'm looking sub directories list which is having 3 character next to the /test directory

Comment: @KannanManokaran Are you saying that using `-type d` returns non-directories?

Comment: no. it is giving sub directories only..i'm doing this on Linux, something i want to do it on AIX

Comment: If AIX `find` supported `-maxdepth`, then the OP's code would work there.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't want to recurse into the directory, a simple wildcard *could* suffice. The baseline is `???/`, meaning "match directory names that have exactly three characters; in the default AIX shell of ksh, you would need to add `.??/` to match "hidden" directories that start with a period and are followed by two characters (assuming you count the period as one of the three; use `.???/` if the period doesn't count).

Beyond that, the only "tricks" are:

- to use a subshell to `cd` into the /test directory; otherwise, you would need to additionally post-process away the leading "/test" strings.
- since we're using a trailing slash `/` to force the wildcard to match directories (versus files), we use `sed` remove the trailing slash from each line.

The one-liner is then:

```
(cd /test; printf '%s\n' ???/ .??/) | sed 's!/$!!'
```

With a sample setup of:

```
mkdir /test
mkdir /test/AAA /test/BBB /test/.AB
touch /test/aaa
```

The sample results are:

```
AAA
BBB
.AB
```

Comment: Note that `???/` (contrary to `zsh`'s `???(/)`) matches both directories and symlinks to directories.