# How to find and print files that are missing in a directory?

Tags: bash, find

I want to find and list all directories that contain a file that ends in .grid in a parent directory `/work/user/folder1/*/*`

```
find /work/user/folder1/*/*/ '!' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name *.grid
```

The next step I want to do is to find and all the directories missing the file that ends in .grid
Basically I want the command to print out missing folders.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` to call `find`!

```
find . -type d \( -exec sh -c 'cd "$0"; find . \( -name . -o -prune \) -name "*.grid" | grep -q .' {} \; -o -print \)
```

This is POSIX-compliant, thanks to this answer:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330372/135943

Also, this will work regardless of spaces, special characters or even newlines in filenames or directory names.  :)

<sub>(N.B.: If you *do* have special characters or newlines in your directory names, you should change that final `-print` primary to whatever action you want to do with the directories, since you won't be able to safely parse the resulting printed list if you just use `-print`.)</sub>

Here is a version with line breaks added in a possibly misguided attempt to aid readability:

```
find . -type d \
  \( \
    -exec sh -c '
      cd "$0";
      find . \( -name . -o -prune \) -name "*.grid" |
        grep -q .
    ' {} \; \
    -o -print \
  \)
```

Comment: I much prefer the line breaks!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.) Create a list of all applicable directories, sort it in alphanumeric order and make sure there are no duplicates. Save the list in a temporary file:

```
find /work/user/folder1/ [...] -type d | sort | uniq > all_directories.txt
```

Step 2.) Create a list of all `*.grid` files.

```
find /work/user/folder1/ [...] -name *.grid > grid_files.txt
```

Step 3.) Work through the list of `*.grid` files, take the directory name of each file, and again make sure there are no duplicates:

```
while read FILENAME
do
    echo $(dirname "$FILENAME")
done < grid_files.txt | sort | uniq > dirs_with_gridfiles.txt
```

Step 4.) Run those two lists together and sort the result again. Now, directories with `*.grid` files should be listed *exactly* twice each, and directories with no `*.grid` files *exactly* once each. So you can tell `uniq` to report only the non-repeated lines:

```
cat all_directories.txt dirs_with_gridfiles.txt | sort | uniq -u > dirs_with_no_gridfile.txt
```

And there you'll have it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two-step solution.  Overall, the procedure is:

1. Find all `*.grid` files in your path, remove the base filename, and `uniq` the list.  This gives you a list of all directories that contain one or more `*.grid` files.

`$ find /work/user/folder1/*/*/ -type f -name *.grid | sed -e 's-[^/]*$--' | 
        sort | uniq > grid-dirs.txt`

2. Find all directories in your path and use `grep` to filter out the directories found in step 1.  This gives you a list of all directories that don't contain any `*.grid` files.

`$ find /work/user/folder1/*/*/ -type d | grep -Fvxf grid-dirs.txt`

For example, suppose:

```
$ find /work
/work
/work/user
/work/user/folder1
/work/user/folder1/AA
/work/user/folder1/AA/AA
/work/user/folder1/AA/DD
/work/user/folder1/AA/CC
/work/user/folder1/AA/BB
/work/user/folder1/AA/BB/foo.grid
```

After step 1, `grid-dirs.txt` is:

```
/work/user/folder1/AA/BB/
```

and the step 2 output is:

```
$ find /work/user/folder1/*/*/ -type d | grep -Fvxf grid-dirs.txt
/work/user/folder1/AA/AA/
/work/user/folder1/AA/CC/
/work/user/folder1/AA/DD/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Bash v4 (or greater) I think you can also do it with one loop looking for all `*.grid` files, plus one inner loop over all directories to list which directories have the files and which don't. With Bash v4 we use one of its options that is usually disabled.

```bash
(
# 'globstar' enables '**' expansions, which instructs
# the shell to search all and below recursively
shopt -s globstar

# Note that '**' is implicitly recursive, no need to specify
# depth. If you do want to specify precise depth, then use a
# '*/' for each wanted depth, like '*/*/*/' for 3 depths
for f in /work/user/folder1/**/*.grid; do
    f="${f##*/}"  # strip directory from found name
    printf '\nNow looking for: %s\n' "$f"
    # A simple '**/' returns directories only
    for d in /work/user/folder1/**/; do
        # simple existence test
        [ -e "${d}${f}" ] && \
            printf '    present in %s\n' "$d" || \
            printf 'not present in %s\n' "$d"
    done
done
)
```

Unfortunately the `**` syntax is not POSIX.

However, if you know the precise depth you need to search, just take the `shopt` command away and turn each `**/` into the precise depth expressed as `*/` repetitions, and it should work well on POSIX shells too.