# Find directories that do not contain a file in only directories proceeding a specific directory

Tags: find, osx, directory

I have a large project for which I'm trying to find directories that don't contain a `*_out.csv` file. I have looked at other similar answers and I think I am almost there.

The problem I'm running into is that I only want to look in directories that proceed `analysis/` but I also don't want to look in a few specific directories that also proceed analysis.

I have set up a small example problem:

```bsh
$ tree
.
├── case1
│   ├── analysis
│   │   ├── test1
│   │   │   ├── gold
│   │   │   └── test1_out.csv
│   │   └── test2
│   └── doc
└── case2
    ├── analysis
    │   ├── test3
    │   │   └── gold
    │   └── test4
    │       └── test4_out.csv
    └── doc

12 directories, 2 files
```

I don't want to look in directories titled `*/doc/*` or `*/gold/*`. My current command is:

```
find . -type d -not -name "doc" -not -name "gold" '!' -exec test -e "{}/*_out.csv" ';' -print
```

Which results in:

```
.
./case1
./case1/analysis
./case1/analysis/test1
./case1/analysis/test2
./case2
./case2/analysis
./case2/analysis/test3
./case2/analysis/test4
```

My ideal output would look like

```
./case1/analysis/test2
./case2/analysis/test3
```

So as you can see, my current `find` command is excluding the `doc` and `gold` directories, but it's not excluding directories which have a `*_out.csv` file and also not excluding directories that don't proceed `analysis/`.

Comment: “Proceed” doesn't make sense here. Did you mean “contain”?

Comment: By "Proceed" I mean subdirectories of `analysis/`

Comment: Are all the `analysis` directories at the same level (e.g. you have `case1/analysis` and `not-a-case/…`) or are there at different levels (e.g. you have `case1/analysis`, `case3/sub/analysis` and you also want to look in `case3`)?

Comment: @Gilles, all the `analysis` folders are at the same level, but sometimes the folder structure is `case3/analysis/test1/test1_out.csv` and other times it can be `case4/analysis/case4_out.csv`.

Comment: Ok. Please edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to look under directories of the form `*/analysis`, excluding certain subdirectories.

Instead of searching everything under `.`, search only under `*/analysis`.

To exclude a subdirectory, use `-prune`. This is an action that tells find not to traverse that subdirectory recursively.

Finally, to test whether a file exists that matches a pattern, you need to invoke a shell. You're invoking `test` directly from `find`, but `test` doesn't do pattern matching, so it's only testing the existence of a file whose name contains a literal `*` character. Invoke `sh`, passing it the name of the directory as an argument: `-exec sh -c '…' {} \;`. In the sh code, expand a wildcard to generate the list of matching files, and check if there is at least one existing file.

```
find ./*/analysis -name "doc" -prune -o -name "gold" -prune -o \
     -type d \! -exec sh -c 'set -- "$0"/*_out.csv; test -e "$1"' {} ';' -print
```

(I assume that there are no dangling symbolic links whose name end with `_out.csv`.)

Answer (score 1):

Your task is a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529264/how-to-find-and-print-files-that-are-missing-in-a-directory).  The same strategy will work:

1. Find all your *_out.csv files, strip off the basename and uniq the list.
2. Find all the directories that you **hope** would have *_out.csv files, and remove the entries in list 1 from the list from step 2.

This script does that, with output descriptors:

```
echo "csv files exist in:"
find . -type f -name \*_out.csv | sed -e 's/\/[^\/]*$//' |  
    sort -u | tee csv-dirs.txt

echo
echo "dirs we hope would have csv's:"
find . -type d | egrep '/analysis/' | egrep -v '/(doc|gold)(/.*|)$' |  
    tee all-dirs.txt

echo
echo "all dirs less the ones that do have csv's:"
egrep -vxFf csv-dirs.txt all-dirs.txt
```

Condensed a little, that could be just:

```
$ find . -type f -name \*_out.csv |  
    sed -e 's/\/[^\/]*$//' | sort -u > csv-dirs.txt
$ find . -type d | egrep '/analysis/' |  
    egrep -v '/(doc|gold)(/.*|)$' | egrep -vxFf csv-dirs.txt
./case1/analysis/test2
./case2/analysis/test3
```