# How to find directory in directory?

Tags: bash, find

How can I find a directory with a certain name but only if it is in another directory with a certain name? For example when I have the following directory structure

```
a
├── b
│   └── e
├── c
│   └── e
└── d
```

I'd like to find the directory 'e', but only when it is located in a directory called 'c'. If possible with the find command alone without using grep.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use GNU `find` with `-path` that searches the entire path for a match:

```
$ find . -path '*/c/e'
./a/c/e
```

That will match any file or directory called `e` which is in a directory called `c`.

Alternatively, if you don't have GNU `find` or any other that supports `-path`, you can do:

```
$ find . -type d -name c -exec find {} -name e \;
./a/c/e
```

The trick here is to first find all `c/` directories and then search only in them for things called `e`.

Comment: `-path` is specified in [POSIX find](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

Comment: Ah, thanks @Quasímodo. I had checked https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html which didn't have it and hadn't realized that the more recent version of POSIX includes it.

Comment: The latter would find `e` anywhere within `c`, right? Not just immediately below. I guess the same could be done with `-path` with something like `-path '*/c/*/e' -o -path '*/c/e'`. (Can't seem to do it with just one pattern.)

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, good point. The second will find `e` anywhere in a directory tree under `c`.

Comment: For an emulation of `-maxdepth 1` in POSIX `find` see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330372/27672).

Comment: @Ruslan why would we want `maxdepth 1` here? The whole point of this question is to make it recursive. If we wanted `-maxdepth 1` we could just do `echo */c/e `.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to find how to address ilkkachu's comment, and erroneously though that `-maxdepth 1` is the solution.

Comment: @Ruslan ah, I see. You may be right, actually. There might be some `-prune` magic to be done here, but I admit I never use `-prune` so I don't really know how to.

Comment: maybe, for the non-gnu solution: `find . -name 'c' -exec find '{}/e' -type d \( -name 'e' -ls -o -prune \) \; 2>/dev/null`  : it seems to work on my machine (to test, I also added files under each directories as otherwise some solutions would list also files under any "c/e" subdirs). to test:  in a subdir: `mkdir -p a b c a/b a/c a/c/e a/c/d/e a/c/d/e/c/e/f/g ; for i in $(find */ -type d -ls); do ( cd "$i" && touch a b c d e ) ; done` (creates wherever it can up to five files under each subdir, except those matching a dir name)  (I corrected the previous comment)

Comment: @OlivierDulac sounds like you have the makings of an answer there. Shame to let it be lost in the comments!

Comment: @terdon thanks, I added an answer with this. I thought you could modify yours (as I stole the idea from you ^^)

Comment: @OlivierDulac `-prune` is deep dark magic for me, I wouldn't dare write an answer with it! :)

Answer (score 5):

Since you have tagged Bash, an alternative is to use [globstar](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

```
shopt -s globstar # Sets globstar if not already set
# Print the matching directories
echo **/c/e/
# Or put all matching directories in an array
dirs=(**/c/e/)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @terdon 's solution, I provide here an alternative version for those without GNU find (that I only could find by following his idea!):

```
find . -type d -name 'c' -exec find '{}/e' -type d \( -name 'e' -ls -o -prune \) \; 2>/dev/null
```

This seems to work on my machine

To test:

```
# add files under each directories as otherwise some solutions would 
# list also files under any "c/e" subdirs ... 
# in a subdir : do  : 
mkdir -p a b c a/b a/c a/c/e a/c/d/e a/c/d/e/c/e/f/g
for i in $(find */ -type d -ls); do ( cd "$i" && touch a b c d e ) ; done 
# this will creates several files under each subdirs, wherever it can (ie, when they don't match a subdir's name).
# then test:
find . -type d -name 'c' -exec find '{}/e' -type d \( -name 'e' -ls -o -prune \) \; 2>/dev/null 
# and it answers only the 2 matching subdirs that match name "c/e":
inode1 0 drwxr-xr-x   1 uid  gid   0 nov.  2 17:57 ./a/c/e
inode2 0 drwxr-xr-x   1 uid  gid   0 nov.  2 18:02 ./a/c/d/e/c/e
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Fd tool:

```
fd -t d --full-path /c/e$
```

https://github.com/sharkdp/fd