# Prune search tree if file is found

Tags: find

I need to search a rather big directory hierarchy for regular files with names matching a particular filename globbing pattern. The hierarchy is so big (both very deep and with some enormous directories) that it would take far too long to take a naive approach:

```bsh
find /top/dir -type f -name 'pattern'
```

(Where `pattern` is some pattern like `*proj*.tgz`.)

Due to the nature of the directory structure, I know I could introduce an optimization to prune the search tree if `find` found a file in a directory. For example, finding one or several files in a particular directory would mean that I wouldn't need to examine any of the subdirectories of that specific directory for other matches.

Since applying `-prune` to a regular file isn't doing the right thing, I can't just do

```bsh
find /top/dir -type f -name 'pattern' -prune
```

Question: How do I avoid searching the subdirectories of the directory that contains the file(s) that matches the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could call an in-line script for each directory.  The script would check whether the pattern matches any regular files in the directory.  If the pattern matches, it outputs (in the general case, *processes* rather than just print) the matching pathnames and prunes the parent directory from the search tree:

```bsh
find /top/dir -type d -exec zsh -c '
    set -- "$1"/pattern(.N)
    [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && exit 1
    printf "%s\n" "$@"' zsh {} \; -prune
```

I'm using the `zsh` shell for the in-line script to access that shell's globbing qualifiers.  The qualifier used here, `(.N)`, ensures that only regular files match the pattern and removes the pattern if there are no matching files.

---

Using `bash` for the in-line script:

```bsh
find /top/dir -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -c '
    unset -v found
    for pathname in "$1"/pattern; do
        if [[ -f "$pathname" ]] && [[ ! -h "$pathname" ]]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
            found=true
        fi
    done
    "${found-false}"' bash {} \; -prune
```

That is, let the in-line script loop over the names matching the pattern in the specific directory, and if any name corresponds to a regular file, process it and set a "flag".  If the flag is set at the end, prune the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the hierarchy of directories, and in each one prune the tree if the flag file (`pattern`) is found, but otherwise search for the wanted files (`*proj*.tgz`)

```
find /top/dir -type d -exec sh -c 'z=$(find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "pattern" -print -quit); [ -n "$z" ]' _ {} \; -prune -o -type f -name '*proj*.tgz' -print
```

I ended up writing a more complex version of this that allowed me to see what was going on. Obviously I had to change `/top/dir`, `pattern`, and `*proj*.tgz` for items that were relevant locally.) I'll include it here for posterity

```
find /top/dir -type d \
    -exec bash -c '
        echo "Considering $*";
        z=$(find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "| %p\n" -name "pattern" -printf "Found flag file\n" -quit);
        [[ -n "$z" ]] && echo "$z";
        [[ "$z" =~ "Found flag file" ]] || { echo "No flag found"; exit 1; }
    ' _ {} \; \
    -printf "Pruning tree\n" -prune \
    -o \
    -type f -name '*proj*.tgz' -print
```

The real solution requires the non-POSIX `find -maxdepth`. The debugging version also requires non-POSIX `find -printf`. There is an [alternate approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330372/100397) for implementing `-maxdepth` that satisfies POSIX, but I haven't used it here; the code is opaque enough as it is.