# How to move directories containing files matching pattern to another directory?

Tags: bash

I have multiple layered sub-directories, and I am trying to relocate all directories which contain files of a pattern into a new parent directory. I want to maintain the contents of the directories I wish to move, whether or not they have files in addition to those matching a pattern.

For example:

```
homedir/subdir/{file.txt, file.png, file.rtf}
homedir/subdir/{file.txt, file.png}
homedir/subdir/{file.txt, file.jpg}
homedir/subdir/subdir/{file.png, file.png, file.mp3}
```

I want each DIRECTORY containing "*.png" (along with any additional non-png contents that may be within the directory) to be moved to /dirPNG

So, the result would be:

```
homedir/subdir/{file.txt, file.jpg}
homedir/dirPNG/subdir/{file.txt, file.png, file.rtf}
homedir/dirPNG/subdir/{file.txt, file.png}
homedir/dirPNG/subdir/subdir/{file.png, file.png, file.mp3}
```

Comment: If `homedir/dirPNG` contained a match to `*.png` should it also move `subdir` and `subdir/*...` too?

Comment: Why don't you name them `subdir1`, `subdir2`, `subdir3` into your example? You can't have different subdirs with same paths.

Comment: @thansisp That's just placeholder name of directories. They have different names in reality.

Comment: @roaima I'm not sure I understand. /dirPNG shouldn't have any matches because it's a folder I'll create to move the results into prior to running the command; so It'll be empty prior to execution of mv. I think. Sorry if I'm not clear. Trying to learn this all as I go.

Comment: You must use different names into your post. Please have a look here: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested `find`. This version requires GNU `find` or similar that supports `-maxdepth` and `-quit`, but there are [workarounds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/100397) available for [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) compatibility.

```
find homedir -depth -type d \
    -exec sh -c '[ -n "$(find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.png" -print -quit)" ]' _ {} \; \
    -exec sh -c 'echo "Move $@"' _ {} \;
```

Replace or supplement `echo "Move $@"` with `mv "$@" /dirPNG` when you are *absolutely sure* the code is doing what you want.

It works by traversing directories depth first, searching for any files matching `*.png` in each directory. If there's a match the directory is moved.

As a result, if you have `homedir/subdir` containing `subsubdir/a.png` and also `b.png`, you'll get `subsubdir` moved before `subdir`, so they become peers in the target directory rather than hierarchical.

If this does not achieve your required result you can try removing `-depth`, but you will receive a large number of `find: ‘subdir’: No such file or directory` type errors during the traversal where `find` tries to descend into a directory that's already been moved. This isn't fatal but it's inelegant.

Regardless, you will get errors if you try to move a directory into the destination if there's a directory with the same name already present. You have not specified what should happen in this instance so an error and a refusal to move will have to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that will do what you need, but **be warned that what you are doing is dangerous if applied to your HOME directory.**

The below script **creates a batch file** to perform the actions.

That allows you to **review the intended actions before** you actually perform the task, so that you may delete any lines that could spell disaster for you.

There are other comments in the script which I suggest you consider for future expanded functionality.

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `
TMP="/tmp/tmp.$$.${BASE}"       ; rm -f ${TMP}

START=`pwd`
BATCH="${START}/${BASE}.batch"

MODE=0
INSENS=0
ONE_PARTITION=""
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case "${1}" in
        "--suffix" ) MODE=1 ; STRNG="${2}" ; pattern_ident="RELOC_${STRNG}" ; shift ; shift ;;
        "--prefix" ) MODE=2 ; STRNG="${2}" ; pattern_ident="RELOC_${STRNG}" ; shift ; shift ;;
        "--single" ) ONE_PARTITION="-xdev" ; shift ;;
        "--insensitive" ) INSENS=1 ; shift ;;
        * ) echo "\n\t ERROR:  Invalid option used on command line.  Options allowed: [ --suffix | --prefix ] \n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ; ;;
    esac
done

if [ ${MODE} -eq 0 -o -z "${STRNG}" ] ; then  echo "\n\t ERROR:  Must specify one of --suffix or --prefix values on the command line.\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ; fi

SEARCH_ROOT="${HOME}"
RELOCN_DIR="${HOME}/${pattern_ident}"

if [ ! -d "${RELOCN_DIR}" ]
then
    mkdir "${RELOCN_DIR}"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then  echo "\n\t ERROR:  Unable to create target directory for directory relocation actions.\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ; fi

fi 2>&1 | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n", $0 ) ; }'

### Ignore start directory itself
### Handling directories with spaces/characters in their name
rm -f "${TMP}.search"*

### Segregate dot dirs from others
find "${SEARCH_ROOT}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | sort >"${TMP}.search.raw"
    awk -F \/ '{ if( index( $NF, "." ) == 1 ) { print $0 } ; }' <"${TMP}.search.raw" >"${TMP}.search"
    awk -F \/ '{ if( index( $NF, "." ) == 0 ) { print $0 } ; }' <"${TMP}.search.raw" >>"${TMP}.search"

##########
#more "${TMP}.search"
#exit 0
##########


while read SEARCH_dir
do
    if [ -z "${SEARCH_dir}" ] ; then  break ; fi

    echo "\t Scanning: ${SEARCH_dir} ..." >&2

    ### insert function to dynamically remap ${PAT} to expanded set for case insensitive
    if [ ${INSENS} -eq 1 ]
    then
        sPAT="[Pp][Nn][Gg]"
    else
        sPAT="${STRNG}"
    fi

##########
#echo "sPAT = ${sPAT}" >&2
#exit 0
##########

    case ${MODE} in
        1)  
#########
#( eval find \"${SEARCH_dir}\" ${ONE_PARTITION} -type f -name \'\*\.${sPAT}\' -print | awk -F'/[^/]*$' '{print $1}' | more >&2 ) <&2
#exit 0
#########

            eval find \"${SEARCH_dir}\" ${ONE_PARTITION} -type f -name \'\*\.${sPAT}\' -print |
                awk -F'/[^/]*$' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
            ;;
        2)  
            eval find \"${SEARCH_dir}\" ${ONE_PARTITION} -type f -name \'${sPAT}\*\' -print |
                awk -F'/[^/]*$' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
            ;;
    esac
done <"${TMP}.search" >"${TMP}.dirsToMove"
if [ ! -s "${TMP}.dirsToMove" ] ; then  echo "\n\t No directories identified for specified pattern. No action taken.\n Bye!\n" ; exit 0 ; fi

echo "\n Starting directory move ..."

#########
#more "${TMP}.dirsToMove"
#exit 0
########

###
### Doing the action direction without a specific visual review could corrupt
### the HOME directory to point of unusability if the wrong directories are acted upon.
###
### Save all action commands into a batch file for manual visual review
### to confirm sanity of actions identified before applying.
###
rm -f "${BATCH}"

while read DirToMove
do
    if [ -n "${DirToMove}" ]
    then
        new=`echo "${DirToMove}" | eval sed \'s\+${SEARCH_ROOT}/\+\+\' `
        echo "mv -fv \"${DirToMove}\" \"${RELOCN_DIR}/${new}\" " 2>&1 | awk '{ printf("%s\n", $0 ) ; }' >>"${BATCH}"
    fi
done <"${TMP}.dirsToMove"
if [ ! -s "${BATCH}" ] ; then  echo "\n\t No directories identified for specified pattern. No action taken.\n Bye!\n" ; exit 0 ; fi

echo "\n Directory move BATCH file was created:\n"
cat "${BATCH}" | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n", $0 ) ; }'
echo ""
wc -l "${BATCH}"


exit 0
exit 0
exit 0
```